# Add token inside localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, formik

I need to store token in localstorage when user authorized but after submitting <Formik/> form it doesn`t happen.

I thought the problem appears because that property doesn`t exist. But console.log(Boolean(data.payload,token)) shows true. Token exists but unable to store it in localStorage.

```
const formikSubmit = async (values) => {
        const data = await dispatch(fetchAuth(values))
        if ("token" in data.payload) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.payload.token)
        } else {
            alert("failed to login")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is token a string?  Do you see any error messages in the console?  How do you know that you are unable to store it in localStorage.  More debugging details please.

Comment: @Yogi yes,  typeof data.payload.token return string

Comment: @Yogi because localstorage is empty even after click. JSON.parse and JSON.stringify can`t solve it

Comment: token is a string value.  Do not use JSON.parse or JSON.stringify with a string as these will cause an error.  Read the value using localStorage.getItem("token")

Comment: Please check the browser debugger console (F12) for error messages.  You can also use the debugger application tab to inspect localStorage keys and values.  The problem is likely very simple, but the question doesn't include enough detail or code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const formikSubmit = async (values) => {
    const data = await dispatch(fetchAuth(values))
    if ("token" in data.payload) {
        window.localStorage.setItem("token", data.payload.token)
    } else {
        alert("failed to login")
    }
}
```

Comment: u mean just add window before? I tried to do it but nothing happens

Comment: are you sure that your redux reducers are working fine ? . could you please provide the data object after form submit

Comment: yes, they working fine for registrationForm and for AuthForm.

Comment: data(pin):null => {user:{_id:'63fa04a24a571d68f8…7PiT-Jj0'}
status(pin):'loading' => 'loaded'

Comment: this object does not contain a key called token !

Comment: idk how is it possible. Token already exists inside object

Comment: sorry . i cant see the object fully can you add the object in your question itself

Comment: you need data object?